# convert fs code to fs-extra using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fs-extra

i have code which used to read directory recursive and with given depth but i have wrote this code
by using `var fs= require("fs");`

so my code look like this

```
async function checkFileLoc(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fsPromises.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return checkFileLoc(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files
    .reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), [])
    .filter((e) => e != null);
}
```

I want same code to be written by using `fs-extra`  package with certain depth which is passed by user
any idea how this code can be converted into `fs-extra` code

Comment: Since `fs-extra` just adds to the already existing functions of `fs`, you should be able to just change the package without having to change the code. Or do you want to try to improve the code through `fs-extra`?

Comment: Just want to try to improve the code @Geshode

Comment: Then you should maybe ask on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.